# Django Users' Preferences

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'd like to know what is the best way to store users' preferences in Django.

Let's say I have three choices users can select.

Based on their selection I want to customize certain templates.

Is it better to save each choice/preference as `BooleanField()` or as a `tuple` of choices?

Boolean:

```
subscription_newsletter = model.BooleanField()
subscription_posts = model.BooleanField()
subscription_promotions = model.BooleanField()
```

Tuple:

```
SUBSCRIPTION_CHOICES = (
    ("newsletter","Newsletter"),
    ("posts", "Posts"),
    ("promotions", "Promotions"),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, whether you want them to be able to choose just one option (then tuples) or many (then booleans).